# Should `stream.async_read_some(null_buffers,handler)` complete immediately or not?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

The context for this: I'm working on implementing a simple stream adaptor on top of an RDMA wrapper library integrating with Boost ASIO.

The issue I'm running into is that the `boost::asio::async_read` aggregator being called by the client code is hanging even when the stream has returned enough data to fill the buffer, if there's no more pending data in the internal receive buffer.  Debugging appears to show that it's calling my stream adaptor's `async_read_some` method with a single buffer of size 0.

The documentation I've found seems to be conflicting on whether that operation should complete immediately or not.  On the one hand, [the AsyncReadStream concept specification](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncReadStream.html) says:

> If the total size of all buffers in the sequence `mb` is 0, the asynchronous read operation shall complete immediately and pass 0 as the argument to the handler that specifies the number of bytes read.

On the other hand, [the overview of `boost::asio::null_buffers`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html) says:

> A `null_buffers` operation doesn't return until the I/O object is "ready" to perform the operation.

(And in fact, elsewhere I'm relying on that to register handlers to be called when the rdma_cm and ibverbs completion channel FDs indicate available events.)  But looking at the implementation of `null_buffers`, it would appear that it's just a static object containing no buffers, so that would seem to satisfy the condition of a sequence with total size of all buffers being 0.

So, I'm confused as to how my `async_read_some` method should handle the case of trying to read 0 bytes.  As a wild guess, maybe it should be something like: on a truly empty sequence like `null_buffers` it should complete only when there's data available in the receive buffer, while if it has a non-empty sequence with total length of the buffers equal to 0 then it should complete immediately regardless of the state of the receive buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Note*** `null_buffers` has been deprecated since Boost 1.66.0: [*"(Deprecated: Use the socket/descriptor wait() and async_wait() member functions.)"*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/null_buffers.html)

> As a wild guess, maybe it should be something like: on a truly empty sequence like null_buffers it should complete only when there's data available in the receive buffer, while if it has a non-empty sequence with total length of the buffers equal to 0 then it should complete immediately regardless of the state of the receive buffer?

No. `null_buffers` are NOT "empty buffers" or "zero-length buffers". It's "no buffer", signalling to the ASIO routines that there *are no buffers* (so the size cannot be logically thought to be zero).

All of the completion notes pertaining to the buffer size are irrelevant, because no buffers are present. The relevant piece of documentation is **[Reactor Style Operations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html).**

You said it correctly: passing `null_buffers` signals that you want a reactor-style operation to weave into the asio event subsystem (meaning, you can async wait for a socket to become ready for reading/writing, and then do the actual IO e.g. by passing the underlying socket handle to a third party API that doesn't support asynchronous IO natively.

Comment: On another search, I actually found that for example `<boost/asio/detail/reactive_descriptor_service.hpp>` has an overload specifically for `async_read_some` on `null_buffers`.  So I guess that would mean that it's different even from the behavior on any other empty container, e.g. `std::vector<boost::asio::mutable_buffer> no_bufs; posix_stream.async_read_some(no_bufs, []{ std::cout << "Completes immediately!\n"; }); posix_stream.async_read_some(boost::asio::null_buffers{}, []{ std::cout << "Ready to read!\n"; });`  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That's exactly what my answer said.

Comment: OK, before when I asked the question I was thinking of the distinction between `vector<mutable_buffer> no_bufs;` and `char dummy; vector<mutable_buffer> one_empty_buf { { &dummy, 0 } };` where the first could also be considered as "no buffers" whereas the second is "a single empty buffer".

Comment: It's very simple. The distinction is _as documented_. Not _as dreamed_. `null_buffers` are `null_buffers`. Nothing less nothing more. Your other suggestions are merely more different things (an empty sequence of buffers is still not the `null_buffers` type).

Comment: Thinking about it all this might be on purpose. After all, there's too many subtly different "equivalent" payloads to specify, there's simply no special case you can safely overload to mean "reactor style" without violating the principle of least surprise. So the API designers went with explicit tag dispatch (`null_buffers`). It's much the same as `std::launch::deffered`, `std::piece_wise_t`, `boost::asio::use_future`, `std::adopt_lock_t` etc.

Comment: The difference with tag dispatch is that `null_buffers` does implement the `MutableBufferSeq` concept whereas tags usually are empty or nearly-empty structs.  So I guess my confusion was that I was thinking of `null_buffers` as just a specially optimized container class like `mutable_buffers_1`.

Comment: Good point. It could be dual, where it **also** doubles as valid buffer sequence for  use with io services that do not explicitly implement reactor style operations.

Comment: OK, thanks.  If you edit to change "Yes." to "No." :) and elaborate that `null_buffers` is different from any other empty sequence of buffers (as well as different from a non-empty sequence of empty buffers) then I can accept the answer.

Comment: Done. (The clarification was already there from the start. It's the very first sentence after the quote)

Comment: `null_buffers` has been deprecated since Boost 1.66.0: _["(Deprecated: Use the socket/descriptor wait() and async_wait() member functions.)"_](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/null_buffers.html)